# Simple like query in sql server return no result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a simple LIKE query on sql server that returns no result when the leading character is the same as the first...

Database tale contains a row with the field 'Lastname' and the value 'Aalesund'

```
select * 
from table 
where LastName like 'A%' -- returns no results
```

if I change the 'Lastname' field to contain 'Alesund' the exact same query returns the correct row.

Any ideas?

Stig

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a leading space in 'Alesund'?

Comment: Given you're from Oslo, I would suspect a funny A, like À, Á, Â, Ä or Å

Comment: Isn't there a weird character like Å http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85?

Comment: So it contains `Aalesund` with a double A but matches `Alesund`? What is your database's default collation and the collation and datatype of the column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Danish/Norwegian collation of Sql server, "aa" is considered a "synonym" for å, Since that was how the letter was written in Denmark before the 1940es. This also means that "aa" is considered the last letter of the alphabet when sorting.

I don't know whether this behavior makes sense in a Norwegian context, but I think the collation is being split in two in Sql server 2012, maybe that will fix it.

UPDATE: According to Wikipedia, the usage of "Aa" as "Å" in Norway is similar to the Danish usage: "Aa" has been abolished by the official organizations standardizing the languages for several decades, but some towns refuse to change their names for historical reasons, and "Aa" is also still common in family names.

Based on this, I would say that failing to find "Aalesund" when doing a search for LIKE "A%" is the most correct behavior in a Norwegian-localized application. If you refrain from using the Danish/Norwegian collation in order to change this, you should be aware that it will change other properties such as sorting of special letters, as mentioned above.

The many different collations named Danish_Norwegian_... will not help you AFAIK. They specify behaviour regarding sensitivity to case, accents, character width, and kana type (the latter is only relevant in Japanese, I believe). "Å" is not considered an accented "A", but a distinct letter. A description of the naming conventions for collations is in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx).

UPDATE 2: Surprisingly, it seems the collation Norwegian_100_CI_AI does what you want. Maybe the usage in Denmark and Norway is different after all...

Comment: Still something unexplained though. Why does `Aa` match `A` in `Alesund` but not in `A%`?

Comment: This sounds like it might be the problem. What collation could I change to to still support norwegian characters? What are the difference between all the different Danish-Norwegian options? (This is not my domain :))

Comment: @MartinSmith the way I read the question, "A%" matches "Alesund", but not "Aalesund". Since "Aalesund" is really "Ålesund", this is the behavior I would expect (as a Danish speaker).

Comment: @JonasH - Ah yes I thought they were changing the search term not the column value. Mystery solved!

Comment: @JonasH 'Invalid collation 'Norwegian_100_CI_AI'.' And if I change the collation on the database. What would the impact be? Would it affect the existing data?

Comment: @stig Are you on Sql server 2005 (or below)? This collation is new in 2008.

Comment: @JonasH currently on 2005. tried to use the 'Norwegian_100_CI_AI' collation on 2008 but  got the error 'Invalid collation' there also. I'll try again. But what are the impact on the database if I change the collation? Database contains content in norwegian, english and german.

Comment: this crap still exist in SQL2012...and microsoft said solve it in SQL2014

Answer (score 1):

That name is sometimes spelled "Ålesund" The little circle over the A is very small in some fonts.  You may be inadvertently copy/pasting "Ålesund" when you try the query with the full name.  Try

```
select *  from table  where LastName like 'Å%'
```